# How to use ActiveRecord to create a has_many relationship without a bridge table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, data-modeling

Sorry, this one is hard to phrase in the title. So here's what I'm trying to do. A workshop has many districts. Each district has exactly one district_contact (actually a district_contact_id). How can I use ActiveRecord to model the relationship between workshop and district_contact? I want to be able to do this:

```
Workshop.district_contacts
```

And get a collection of the actual user objects. Right now, I've done it using a short function:

```
  def district_contacts
    district_ids = []
    self.districts.each do |district|
      if district.contact_id
        district_ids << district.contact_id
      end
    end
    User.find(district_ids)
  end
```

Comment: you can simplify this function using map.  So district_ids = self.districts.map(&:contact_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model associations should look something like this.

```
class Workshop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :districts
  has_many :district_contacts, through: disctricts
end

class District < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workshop
  has_one :district_contract
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Define associations in the Workshop model:

```
has_many :districts
has_many :district_contacts, through: disctricts
```

Comment: apparently I can't make a single character edit, but you added an extra 'c' in the last districts